# Mono for Android Application Error Handling

Tags: android, error-handling, xamarin.android

Obviously with code, errors can occur anywhere.  So without having try/catch blocks all over the place (which as I understand it is major overhead) how do I allow errors to bubble up to the application level and then handle them there?  Or at the very least, record the error somehow for troubleshooting?  I found information on an product called ACRA, but the setup instructions are geared for Eclipse projects. I am using Mono for Android in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this project that writes crash info to google docs.  [Android Crasher](https://github.com/soundnRg/Crasher/tree/)

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of an "It depends" question.

The appropriate handling of an errors is going to depend on what the recovery strategy needs to be, how much information you want the user to see etc.

I wouldn't worry how many Try/Catch blocks you use - just use them wherever you need to handle an error that gets thrown - if they're everywhere, your strategy is probably wrong.

It terms of logging and later interrogation, you can log caught errors using the **Android.Util.Log** class.

These can be interrogated (provided you're debugging on your own device) using [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

There's some more info on logging and Logcat [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log).